# call a function that asks for (const char *args)

Tags: string, arduino, arguments

Hi I have a function in my arduino like this:
    void cmdAlarm(const char *args)
    {
    ......
    }

usually the function gets called via serial terminal, how can I call the function outside of the serial interface and call the function with a string like this as parameter.

```
String functionParameter = "ALARM 1 20:33"
```

So I'm trying to call my function like this, but it won't work.

```
// call the Alarm function
cmdAlarm(functionParameter);
```

Here is the error message:

```
error: cannot convert 'String' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to
'void cmdAlarm(const char*)'
```

Any ideas, how I can convert my string into const char * ????

thanks guys

Comment: Please define  "it won't work".

Comment: Also, is that a `string` (possibly C++ `std::string`) or a `String`? You might want to add a language-tag.

Comment: It's code for Arduino Uno. It's C

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for [Convert String to Char array](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. It seems like my function doesn't understand the arguments provided. here is how I tried it:
    String asmString = "ALARM 1 20:33"
    char TempTweet[asmString.length() + 1];             
    asmString.toCharArray(TempTweet, asmString.length() + 1);
    cmdAlarm(TempTweet);

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const char *param = "ALARM 1 20:33";
cmdAlarm(param);
```

Comment: Hi, neither of the suggestions worked, I'm wondering what my actual string looks like in HEX. any idea, how I can compare an entry from the serial command line (in hex-values) to my string in hex values (aka my string converted to char array...)??
Please let me know. I'm not getting an error message. i can compile but my function doesn't know what to do with the argument